# Where is the From address set for this batch class?

Tags: email-template, singleemailmessage, org-wide-email

Our site has a scheduled batch job to send a templated mailing. It uses one of our Org Wide Addresses as the From. Please notice that the existing code does **not** have a `setOrgWideEmailAddressId()` method call, and yet it works.

I don't see where the From address is set or stored in the code, template, record, or contacts. It's not the email address of the template author, the job owner, or the record owners.

How is that particular address being selected out of several Org Wide Addresses?

```
public void execute( Database.BatchableContext bc, list<Object__c> scope ) {
        
    EmailTemplate tmpl = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='TEMPLATE_NAME'];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for (Object__c item: scope) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTemplateId(tmpl.id);
        mail.setWhatid(item.id);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(item.Contact__c);
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        sendTo.add(item.Contact__r.Email);
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        msgList.add(mail);
    }
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(msgList,false);
}
```

Comment: Is the sender something other than `no-reply@salesforce.com`?

Comment: Yes, it's one of our Org Wide Addresses, a real mailbox, but I don't know why it's that specific one instead of the others.

Comment: Email templates never define the from (or to) address, that is the responsibility of the Email Alert, Apex Code, or Flow Email action. In your case, the batch job's running user may have set up a default from address in their settings. I'd use the [mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setOrgWideEmailAddressId)

Comment: "may have set up a default from address in their settings". Where is that?
This block of code is currently working without setting a From address, and I don't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you must first set up a email address by navigating to
Setup -> Administration Setup -> Email Administration -> Organization-Wide Addresses menu. Once you have created an org-wide address. Then get id of that email address and use it as setOrgWideEmailAddressId(Id).
Also you can query as below to get org wide email address:

```
List<OrgWideEmailAddress> owEmailList = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'doNotReply@test.com'];
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
if ( !owEmailList.isEmpty() ) {
    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owEmailList[0].Id);
}
```

Comment: I have clarified the question.